# Interpreter throws a run time error when I keep constructor name same as class name?

Tags: python

```
class animal():
   name = 'Tiger'
   def animal(self,name):
       self.name = name
   def show(self):
       print(self.name)

/*ins = animal()
ins.show()
# OUTPUT = Tiger
ins = animal('Lion')
Type Error: this constructor takes no arguments
*/
```

when I keep constructor name as init all works well.I am not getting why there is type error when constructor name is same as class name?

Comment: If you don't have a function named `__init__`, you don't have an initialization function. You have a number of misunderstandings about how Python works. I recommend something introductory to help you get a better foundation. 1) There is no traditional compiler. Python is interpreted. 2) `TypeError` is runtime, not parse-time. 3) If you didn't define an `__init__` method, you didn't define an initializer. This is made evident by the fact you got some output before the error. Last, If you're going to inline the program's output, please make it a comment so it won't cause syntax errors.

Answer (score 3):

In Python, unlike C++/Java the constructor is not named after the class, you should use **init** to achieve constructor functionality. Read more about it [here](http://www.diveintopython.net/object_oriented_framework/defining_classes.html)

More specifically:

> C++ programmers may find it odd that Python classes don't have explicit constructors and destructors. Python classes do have something similar to a constructor: the **init** method.

Answer (score 2):

As @Ishay mentioned, python don't have named constructor.

Following should solve your problem

```
class animal():
   def __init__(self, name = 'Tiger'):
       self.name = name
   def show(self):
       print(self.name)

ins = animal() #Class instance without animal name
ins.show()    
Tiger

ins = animal('Lion') #Class instance with animal name
ins.show()
Lion
```